# Magento Dashboard Graph

Tags: adminhtml

I'm wondering if anyone knows what I would need to do to adjust the dashboard to show the last day (since midnight) instead of the last 24 hours.

Comment: You mean to change the text?

Comment: No I don't mean to just change the text.  I would like it to show more useful information.  As in how much I sold today, VS the last 24 hours so I have a defined start and stop period where I can really tell how my business is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite the block `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection` and override the method `getDateRange` as follows:

```
public function getDateRange($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $returnObjects = false)
{
    $dateEnd   = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
    $dateStart = clone $dateEnd;

    // go to the end of a day
    $dateEnd->setHour(23);
    $dateEnd->setMinute(59);
    $dateEnd->setSecond(59);

    $dateStart->setHour(0);
    $dateStart->setMinute(0);
    $dateStart->setSecond(0);

    switch ($range)
    {
        case '24h':
            $dateEnd = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
            $dateEnd->addHour(1);
            $dateStart = clone $dateEnd;
            // OLD: use the last 24 hours
            // $dateStart->subDay(1);
            // NEW: use the current day since midnight
            $dateStart->setMilliSecond(0);
            $dateStart->setSecond(0);
            $dateStart->setMinute(0);
            $dateStart->setHour(0);
            break;

        case '7d':
            // substract 6 days we need to include
            // only today and not hte last one from range
            $dateStart->subDay(6);
            break;

        case '1m':
            $dateStart->setDay(Mage::getStoreConfig('reports/dashboard/mtd_start'));
            break;

        case 'custom':
            $dateStart = $customStart ? $customStart : $dateEnd;
            $dateEnd   = $customEnd ? $customEnd : $dateEnd;
            break;

        case '1y':
        case '2y':
            $startMonthDay = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('reports/dashboard/ytd_start'));
            $startMonth = isset($startMonthDay[0]) ? (int)$startMonthDay[0] : 1;
            $startDay = isset($startMonthDay[1]) ? (int)$startMonthDay[1] : 1;
            $dateStart->setMonth($startMonth);
            $dateStart->setDay($startDay);
            if ($range == '2y') {
                $dateStart->subYear(1);
            }
            break;
    }

    $dateStart->setTimezone('Etc/UTC');
    $dateEnd->setTimezone('Etc/UTC');

    if ($returnObjects) {
        return array($dateStart, $dateEnd);
    } else {
        return array('from' => $dateStart, 'to' => $dateEnd, 'datetime' => true);
    }
}
```

The code in the `case '24h'` block has been changed. This should be enough.

Hint: Grep for `24h` under `app/code/core/Mage` to find all the places which are relevant for this functionality.