# Show current day orders on Magento Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, dashboard

Currently, when we login to magento admin, it shows the order amount from last 24 hours by default. Is there a way to show Current Date (today) order amount as default?

A detailed solution will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the difference between last 24 hs and current date for you?

Comment: Have edit the question. Todays sales are not equal for sales from last 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Orders/Grid.php`
to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Orders/Grid.php
```

goto Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Orders_Grid and goto  _prepareCollection...

**change: from**

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
            ->addItemCountExpr()
            ->joinCustomerName('customer')

            ->orderByCreatedAt();
```

to

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
            ->addItemCountExpr()
            ->joinCustomerName('customer');

            $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);


         $collection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
            'from'  => $todayStartOfDayDate,
            'to'    =>  $todayEndOfDayDate,                    
        ));
```

Comment: Hi Amit Bera, i tried your solution but still does not work. do you know any reason? i flushed cache as well.

Comment: Dont change code in core files. That is plain wrong.

Comment: ^ No one changed core code here. It was copied to the local namespace.  Please pay attention.

Comment: @SiGriffiths you might not be aware of edits for sure.

Comment: i am sorry but the solution is NOT working. Can someone else provide an solution?

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31023/magento-dashboard-graph